Vite 5 not importing scss variables
For some background we have a bunch of theme colors provided by a designer and are trying to integrate them into a single source of truth as they change often during the prototyping phase.
To this end we have consolidated them into a single primary.module.scss file like so:
$white: #ffffff;
$black: #000000;

$grey10: #edf2f1;
$grey20: #c9d0d1;
// ....

:root {
  --white: #{$white};
  --black: #{$black};

  --grey-10: #{$grey10};
  --grey-20: #{$grey20};
  // ....
}

:export {
  white: $white;
  black: $black;

  grey10: $grey10;
  grey20: $grey20;
  // ...
}

This (in the past) exports them both as global CSS variables and as typescript variables to be used in our MUI theme.
However when starting a new project the following error started showing up on the following code (for example):
import colors from './colors/primary.module.scss';

console.log(colors['blue60'])

this now outputs _blue60_c2dde8 (not the value of the color) rather than the correct value of #0073e6 as it used to.
Has anyone seen this when upgrading to vite 5?
UPDATE: If it helps, colors is not visible in the debugger and logging it returns [Object: null prototype] {}
Example of it "working" in the past: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/17858

This occurs under test unless the following is set in the vitest config:
css: true

